# Matching exclusive search groups in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I've been struggling to come up with a reg-ex fix within my [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) library...

It implements [a formatting method](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/blob/master/lib/formatting.js#L508) which does a verification for a string to determine whether it is a `simple` one or not, based on the following rules:

The string is defined as `simple` when:

- it is a same-case single word, without spaces
- it can contain underscores, and can even start with them
- it can contain digits and $, but cannot start with those

Those a basically the rules for determining when an SQL alias needs to be wrapped in double-quotes or not.

So if I isolate the test logic:

```
const m = name.match(/[a-z_][a-z0-9_$]*|[A-Z_][A-Z0-9_$]*/);

console.log(m && m[0] === name ? 'simple' : 'complex');
```

It passes tests in all cases, except when we have an underscore and then capital letters, like this: `_A` or `__ABC`. At the same time, it works for `_a` and `__abc`.

How to change the regular expression to make it work for those special cases also?

Thank you!

Comment: The reason this doesn't work is that you put the lowercase alternative first: It will match the underscores there, then won't be able to match the uppercase letters anymore and switch to a new match with the second alternative. Would adding word boundaries an option? `\b(?:[A-Z_][A-Z0-9_$]*|[a-z_][a-z0-9_$]*)\b`

Comment: Is `_` a legal input?

Comment: @GalAbra yes! Here're all my tests: https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/blob/master/test/formatSpec.js#L590

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add metacharacters `^` (beginning of the string) and `$` (end of the string) to your regular expression, it will work as expected for uppercase words too, and also let simplify condition on output:

```
const m = name.match(/^([a-z_][a-z0-9_$]*|[A-Z_][A-Z0-9_$]*)$/);

console.log(m ? 'simple' : 'complex');
```

Comment: I've got over 20 tests thrown at it, and they all passed. Brilliant, thank you much! I was almost there, but my mistake was that I grouped them like this `/^([a-z_][a-z0-9_$]*)|([A-Z_][A-Z0-9_$]*)$/`, i.e. I thought it needed 2 groups there, didn't occur to me to stack it all up into a single group :)